# Submit action using an automatic get method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I am developing a wordpress plugin and am having a bit of trouble with my form submission. When activated the plugin essentially creates a little contact form with three fields so that a user would be able to enter in their name, email and phone number and then click submit which would then validate the code and store it in a database.

The strange thing is when clicking the Submit button the data seems to be sent using a get method as it is displayed in the url. I am handling the click of the button with an ajax post in a javascript file though. Here is the form code:

```
    <div id="formwrapper" style="border:solid;border-color:red;">
        <form name="contact" action="">

            <label><strong>Contact Us</strong></label>

            </br>
            </br>

            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name & Surname">
            <label class="error" for="name" id="nameErr">Please enter your name and surname</label>

            </br>
            </br>

            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            <label class="error" for="email" id="emailErr">Please enter a valid email address</label>

            </br>
            </br>

            <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Cell or Landline">
            <label class="error" for="phone" id="phoneErr">Please enter your cell or landline number</label>

            </br>
            </br>

            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_button">

        </form>
    </div>
```

And this is the javascript I am using to handle the click of the button:

```
$(".button").click(function() {

            $(".error").hide();

            var name = $("input#name").val();
            if (name == "") {

                $("label#nameErr").show();
                $("input#name").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var email = $("input#email").val();
            if (email == "") {

                $("label#emailErr").show();
                $("input#email").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            if (phone == "") {

                $("label#phoneErr").show();
                $("input#email").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var datastring = 'name=' + name + '&email' + email + '&phone' + phone;

            $.ajax({

                type:"POST";,
                url: "bin/process.php",
                data: datastring,
                success: function() {

                    $('#formwrapper').html("div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact form submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });
                }
            });
            alert "hello";
            return false;


        }
```

Not only does clicking the button not properly post the values, it seems to activate some sort of search function within wordpress as all the posts disappear and return with a "Sorry , no posts matched your criteria" message.

Comment: You should type:"GET"; instead

Comment: `name="submit"` can cause issues. http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/form-access/#faComMis

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your js code

```
alert "hello";
```

is not valid use:

```
alert("hello");
```

Due to this your `return false` does not get triggered and the form submits as normal.

Use event.preventDefault instead of returning false so that you will detect errors like this better

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   ...

});
```

And as Joe Frambach points out another syntax error is in your ajax options

```
type:"POST";,
```

should be

```
type:"POST",
```

Comment: There's another one: `type:"POST";,` is a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".button").click(function() {

        $(".error").hide();

        var name = $("input#name").val();
        if (name == "") {

            $("label#nameErr").show();
            $("input#name").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var email = $("input#email").val();
        if (email == "") {

            $("label#emailErr").show();
            $("input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        if (phone == "") {

            $("label#phoneErr").show();
            $("input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var datastring = 'name=' + name + '&email' + email + '&phone' + phone;

        $.ajax({

            type:"GET";,
            url: "bin/process.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function() {

                $('#formwrapper').html("div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>Contact form submitted!</h2>")
                .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
                    $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                });
            }
        });
        alert "hello";
        return false;


    }
```

Comment: You totally missed the syntax error on the *same line*!